# Set of items based on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

Create a set from a list of tuples based on the first element of the tuple.

`[(name1, 1), (name2, 2), (name1, 3)]` should return `[(name1, 1), (name2, 2)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
someList = [('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('x', 3)]
s = set()
for item in someList:
    if not any(item[0] in element for element in s):
        s.add(item)
```

Did you mean something like this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `item[0] == element`

Answer (score 2):

Simple and effective solution:

```py
list_of_tuples = [('name1', 1), ('name2', 2), ('name1', 3)]
output = []
seen_names = set()  # just typing {} initializes a dictionary
for tuple in list_of_tuples:
    name = tuple[0]
    if name not in seen_names:
        output.append(tuple)
        seen_names.add(name)
print(output)
```

This will print the desired output, `[('name1', 1), ('name2', 2)]`.

Comment: This is the best of the three answers from Jun 5. However it is  simpler to just use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Assume:

```
l = [('name1', 1), ('name2', 2), ('name1', 3)]
```

Two liner:

```
s = set()
r = [s.add(i[0]) or i for i in l if i[0] not in s]
```

Result:

```
[('name1', 1), ('name2', 2)]
```

Comment: This doesn't print the tuples, only the keys.

Comment: @JossieCalderon What do you mean?You used `print(s)` instead of `print(r)`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a modified version of the group by pattern. Since we only want the first value we can just use `dict.setdefault`.

```py
input_ = [("name1", 1), ("name2", 2), ("name1", 3)]
```

```py
grouper = {}
for key, value in input_:
    grouper.setdefault(key, value)

print(list(grouper.items()))
# [('name1', 1), ('name2', 2)]
```